# How to call/run a method only one time in python

Tags: python

I want to call/run a method only onetime I tried this but it didn't wotk:

```
class S ()
    _int_(self)
      self.xxx = True # i tried with and without
    def Packet (event):
       if (xxx == True):  
           self.f(event, xxx)
           print xxx
       else:
           ....
    def f (event):
       print "something"
       Do_Somthing
       xxx=False
```

the problem xxx is still true

Best regards
Amer

Comment: Once per `S` instance? Once per execution of the script? Once ever?

Comment: Can you please change your code so that it runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `xxx` to `self.xxx`.

The `xxx = False` creates a new name binding instead of assigning to the field in your object.

Also, there are also some other syntax errors in your code. Is this the actual code you are running? The code you posted shouldn't run.

Comment: Every instance of `xxx` has to be changed to `self.xxx`.

Answer (score 3):

The whole class's syntax seems wrong to me. You can do something like this

```
class S:
    def __init__(self):        # Initializer function for instance members
        self.flag = True

    def myMethod(self):        # Actual method to be called
        if self.flag:
            ....
            ....
            self.flag = False
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import count

class S ()

    def __init__(self)
      self.xxx = count()

    def Packet(self, event):
       if next(self.xxx) == 0:  
           self.f(event)
       else:
           ....

    def f(self, event):
       print "something"
       #Do_Something
```